# Find the name of a repeater control on form load

Tags: c#, code-behind

When my page loads, I have a link to update a record on each record in a repeater control.

The link looks like this when I hover over it with my mouse:

```
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$AcctRepeater$ctl03$LinkUpdate','')
```

I am also using paging on my form.  So, when I click this link, it does a postback that recreates the paging.

What I want to do is to check, on page_load, to see if the LinkUpdate link is what is causing the page load.  If so, I don't want to process the paging piece.

So, can anyone tell me how to check, on page_load, to see what caused the page load?  I tried poking around with the sender piece of **protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)** but couldn't figure it out.  Also, **e** doesn't understand **item** or **CommandName** until after the Page_Load piece has completed, so I can't use those either.

Ultimately, what I want to end up with is something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        var MySortVal = cboSortBy.SelectedValue;
        var MySortVal2 = Session["SSortBy"];
        if (Session["SSortBy"] != null)
        {
            lblSortOrder.Text = Session["SSortBy"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            lblSortOrder.Text = "X";
        }

        Show_Data();
        LoadGroups();
    }
    else if (**this page has been reloaded because of the link**)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        var MySortVal = cboSortBy.SelectedValue;
        var MySortVal2 = Session["SSortBy"];
        if (Session["SSortBy"] != null)
        {
            lblSortOrder.Text = MySortVal;
        }
        else
        {
            lblSortOrder.Text = "X";
        }

        Show_Data();
        LoadGroups();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked this?

```
Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"]
```

It should take the value of the first parameter of __doPostBack which in case of your link should be 'ctl00$MainContent$AcctRepeater$ctl03$LinkUpdate'

Comment: BRILLIANT!!  That just saved my life.  I just substituted the following for the **else if** statement above: else if (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"].Contains("Update"))